# Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash. in fvm flutter, linux

Tags: flutter

Once I change the global version of fvm, the following error occurs:

```
$ fvm
Can't load Kernel binary: Invalid SDK hash.
/Users/lukepighetti/.pub-cache/bin/fvm: line 15: pub: command not found
```

Answer (score 4):

It works for me when I execute `dart pub global activate fvm`.

Comment: I got this after I ran `fvm dart pub global activate fvm` so maybe caused by dartception, running this fixed it for me

Comment: https://github.com/fluttertools/fvm/issues/100#issuecomment-671026547

Answer (score 1):

oh ok, this doesn't seem to be an FVM error, as it happens before running FVM.

I would try doing a dart pub global activate fvm again, and/or a dart pub cache repair.

Also, only way to avoid doing doing the cache repair every time is to use fvm per project and try to leave the global version the same.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of the older solutions worked for me. To resolve on Mac, I had to do the following:

```
rm -rf ~/.pub-cache
dart pub global activate fvm
```